# Meaning of "On" in "Roll On"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, headlinese, figurative-language

I am not sure about the meaning of "on" in:

> [link](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/world/2014/07/08/ukraine-rolls-on-separatists-while-russia-holds-back/12364479/?utm_source=feedblitz&utm_medium=FeedBlitzRss&utm_campaign=usatoday-newstopstories)
>   Ukraine rolls ***on*** separatists while Russia holds back

What does "on" meaning here?   Does it mean Ukraine tanks/vehicles ran over the separatist soldiers?

Answer (score 2):

"Roll" can be used in the sense of "to begin moving" (definition 4b at [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll)).  This is often used in a military context to indicate the mobilization of forces, in preparation for a conflict.

In context, it's clear that Ukraine has activated some portion its army and is moving them in for a possible engagement against hostile forces.  The obvious next question, then, is "what hostile force do they expect to engage?" and the answer to that is "separatists".

Thus, "Ukraine *[the military]* rolls *[begins moving to engage]* on *[in the direction of*, or *with the intent to engage the forces of]* separatists."

(If the Ukraine had literally driven their tanks over separatist soldiers, the headline would probably have said something like "Ukrainian tanks run over separatist soldiers in battle at [place]"; the headline would be as clear as possible about the actual violence.)

Answer (score 0):

It does not mean that the separatists were physically run over by vehicles.

It instead is more like **an abbreviation** coupled with a *colloquialism*, namely 'roll'. The sentence essentially means:

> Ukraine **initiates action** *on the issue of* the separatists while Russia holds back [ie does nothing]

Comment: So, "roll on" is a slang expression?

Comment: not so much slang as a colloquialism

Comment: Is there a dictionary definition for "roll on" that would fit this usage?

Comment: I've no idea - search for it. It is also a British English idiom meaning 'hurry up', in a way. You might say 'Roll on next Tuesday, I'm off on vacation!'